# Updating a property within a list where another property condition is met

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, lambda

I currently have the following expression to update the `IsUnread` property against all items within my list object.

```
myList.ForEach(x => x.IsUnread = true);
```

However, I'd like to apply a condition where the `IsUnread` property is only updated to true where another property (in the same object) meets a certain condition, in this case, where `x.UnreadCount > 0`

What's the cleanest/best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added brackets for clarity:

```
myList.ForEach(x => x.IsUnread = (x.UnreadCount > 0));
```

Comment: Thanks. A nice compact, neat solution :)